# NPM Build error related to Vuetify in nuxt/vuetify package?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuetify-tabs

When I run `npm run build`, it returns this error:

> import installComponents from "!../node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/runtime/installComponents.js"
>   | import { VApp } from 'vuetify/lib/components/VApp';
>   | import { VAppBar } from 'vuetify/lib/components/VAppBar';
>    @ ./.nuxt/App.js 10:0-49 12:14-23
>    @ ./.nuxt/index.js
>    @ ./.nuxt/client.js
>    @ multi ./.nuxt/client.js

Comment: ```You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.```
And this  one too

Comment: Can you show here in your code you're actually making this `import` ?

Comment: @Djip Everywhere in components i import `vuetify` component i guess its all about `vuetify-loader`

Comment: So you aren't using the following implementation? https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module

Comment: Yes,  actually iam using this one

Comment: Then can you please show the code where you're trying to `import installComponents`

Comment: Don't worry i fixed the bug was in `nuxt.config.js`
@Djip Thank You.